# How to correctly include multiple .cpp files in eosiocpp -o?

Tags: compilation

I am trying to include a [JSON-Parsing library](https://github.com/MJPA/SimpleJSON) into my smart contract. There are only two .hpp/.cpp files to link which are in the same folder as the contract. `JSON and JSONValue`

In my contracts header file I use

```
#include "JSON.h" //in JSON.h the JSONValue.h is included
...

//@abi action
void test(const std::string &pToParse);
...
EOSIO_ABI(Test, (test));
```

In my contracts .cpp file I call this method:

```
void VectorTest::test(const std::string& pToParse){
    ... 
    JSON::Parse(pToParse.c_str());
}
```

When I compile it with the following commands no errors are generated:

```
eosiocpp -o contracts/test.wast contracts/test.cpp contracts/JSON.cpp contracts/JSONValue.cpp
eosiocpp -g contracts/test.abi contracts/test.cpp
```

But when I try to push it I get some Runtime error that there is **no apply function**.

```
900434ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:405           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction
900434ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3070002 wasm_execution_error: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Smart contract's apply function not exported; non-existent; or wrong type
    {}
    thread-0  wasm_eosio_validation.cpp:91 validate

    {"_pending_console_output.str()":""}
    thread-0  apply_context.cpp:62 exec_one
```

I cross checked the `test.wast` file and searched for `apply` but there is no apply function.

Am I doing something wrong or do I try to achieve something which is impossible?

---

EDIT

Also this command does not work:

```
eosiocpp -o contracts/test.wast contracts/*.cpp
```

It always seems like it would just include the JSON-cpp files into the WAST.

Comment: include your other cpp file to your main cpp file like #include "xxx.cpp"

Comment: Isn't this considered bad coding style in cpp?

Comment: Have defined the apply function yourself or have you used EOS_ABI that creates the apply function?

Comment: I have used EOS_ABI Macro. Including the cpp files into the contract worked btw - but I still want to know how to use eosiocpp with multiple files

Comment: @TeeAttack42 you can't, see the system contract, it also include the cpp file

Comment: @KemmyGuo but if you run eosiocpp -h it will say you can include additional files - however I will put this in an "workaround answer" - thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround based on @KemmyGuo 's comment:

You can include the additional .cpp files (which have to be in the same folder) into your contracts .cpp file.

**Disclaimer: this is not a good C++ coding style, but it works for the moment.**

In my case inside the test.cpp this did the trick

```
#include "test.h"
#include "JSON.cpp"
#include "JSONValue.cpp"

void Test::test(const std::string& pToParse){
    ... 
    JSON::Parse(pToParse.c_str());
}
```

Then you can run as usual

```
eosiocpp -o contracts/test.wast contracts/test.cpp
eosiocpp -g contracts/test.abi contracts/test.cpp
```